# ctags vs GNU id-tools?

Tags: ctags, navigation

I stumbled upon **mkid tools** in `tips.txt` and tried it out (on C code). In terms of navigating to definitions, I thought it was identical to using **ctags** except for the fact that the `ID` file (generated by `mkid`) is smaller in size (for the same project) than the `tags` file.

Any thoughts on why one might prefer one over the other (other than the fact that vim has in built support for ctags)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vim help alludes to the primary distinction as follows

```
But sometimes you wish you could jump to all the places where
a function or variable is being used.
```

tags can be only used to jump to where identifiers are *defined*.  id-tools is capable of storing all places an identifier is used, which tag files cannot store.

On the other hand, tags have much better integration with vim.  There are at least 14 maps and commands dedicated to tags and vim natively stores your tag history in the tag stack to make navigating code easier.  To use id-tools conveniently in vim you are suggested to add maps to your vimrc and you don't any other nice features.
In this respect, id-tools is treated  like a smarter and faster *grep*.